# Dynamic method access modifier

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I would like to restrict access to methods, depending on the type passed in. In my particular situation, I am developing a UDP "manager" if you will.

I want my `UDPManager` to be used for different things. For example, I might have 1 `UDPManager` for the communications between client and server, and another `UDPManager` to handle the communications between server and another server.

I have defined an `enum` which specifies the type of `UDPManager`. So for example, `ManagerType.A = 1` and...
`ManagerType.B = 2`

The `UDPManager` has certain events that can be subscribed to and I do not want them available if these events are not relevant, given the type of `UDPManager`.

Here is an example of a class

```
public class Something
{
    public int SomethingsType { get; set; }
    public void A() { }
    public void B() { }
}
```

How can I make it so that if `SomethingsType == MessageType.A`, then `MessageType.B` is not available (ie it is private)?

For further clarity, if I type:

```
Something something = new Something();
someting.SomethingsType = 1
```

I do not want `something.B()` to be available.

**UPDATE**

I apologise for mentioning `runtime`. What I mean is, I do not want said method (`B`) available if said `SomethingsType` is `A`.

Comment: its not possible. you can always invoke methods with reflection even if it is private.

Comment: That stuff is enforced by the compiler. It's meaningless at runtime. In your mind, what does "is not available (ie it is private)" mean *at runtime*? What do you expect to happen, when the compiler compiles code that calls `something.B()` (because it's public in the source file), and later on the method suddenly becomes private?

Comment: Implement `SomethingA`, `SomethingB` etc. Then use a factory method given `ManagerType`.

Comment: Is not it the reason why inheritance exists? Manager is a parent and ManagerA, ManagerB are children no?

Comment: What you may actually want here is for the same class to implement multiple interfaces, which include different subsets of a larger set of features.

Comment: All the nopes.  If you want to cause yourself mischief, simply grab a hammer and hit yourself in the head with it.  It's quicker and is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @mxmissile Would you mind giving an example or linking to one?

Comment: Sounds like a textbook [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to rethink the fundamental structure of your API.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry, no idea why I had runtime on the mind! Please see my update.

Comment: Are you *actually* asking for one public method to change its behaviour under the covers based on `SomethingsType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces to the rescue:

```
public interface IUdpManagerA
{
    void A();
}

public interface IUdpManagerB
{
    void B();
}

public class UdpManager : IUdpManagerA, IUdpManagerB
{
    public void A() { }
    public void B() { }             
}

public class UdpManagerFactory
{
     private UdpManager Create() => new UdpManager();
     public IUdpManagerA CreateOfA() => Create();
     public IUdpManagerB CreateOfB() => Create();
}

UdpManagerFactory factory = new UdpManagerFactory();
IUdpManagerA a = factory.CreateOfA();
IUdpManagerB b = factory.CreateOfB();
```

Interfaces are a powerful tool to publish certain members while others can remain hidden.

While you might say *yeah, but you can always cast `IUdpManagerA` to `IUdpManagerB` and vice versa to gain access to hidden members*, and my answer is **this isn't safe because there's no clue that `IUdpManagerA` also implements `IUdpManagerB` and vice versa.

**Oh, and I forgot to mention that you should throw away the `ManagerType` enumeration, because with interfaces you can always check if a given instance is *A* or *B***:

```
object instance = factory.CreateA();

if(instance is IUdpManagerA)
{
}

if(instance is IUdpManagerB)
{
}
```

or using `as` operator:

```
object instance = factory.CreateA();
IUdpManagerA a = instance as IUdpManagerA;
IUdpManagerB b = instance as IUdpManagerB;

if(a != null)
{
} 
else if(b != null)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great. What is this design pattern called?

Comment: @pookie Factory method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: @pookie And the other thing, it's just leveraging OOP/polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

This is an *extreme* simple version of a factory build method based of an enum:

```
    public enum ManagerType
    {
        A,B
    }

    public abstract class UDPManager
    {

    }

    public class SomethingA : UDPManager
    {
        public void A()
        {}
    }

    public class SomethingB : UDPManager
    {
        public void B()
        {}
    }

    public class UdpManagerFactory
    {
        public UDPManager Build(ManagerType type)
        {
            if (type == ManagerType.A)
                return new SomethingA();

            if(type == ManagerType.B)
                return new SomethingB();

            throw new Exception("type not found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this way would work too, but feel that Matias' answer is more suitable.